# But instead serves as both interupt and continuation (commas)

Tags: commas

I have a very complex, long sentence.

*The Fire This Time* focuses not on the "black rage" that occurred after Michael Brown, a black eighteen year old "unarmed kid," was shot, but instead examines the **end sentence**.

Do I need a comma after instead?

Comment: Ignoring the syntactically optional [defining relative clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-relative-clauses) *a black eighteen year old "unarmed kid"*, structurally what you have is *[subject] focuses not on X but instead on Y*. Where the comma is *optional* (as indeed is the word "instead") - effectively a stylistic choice / matter of opinion.

Comment: @FF I agree it's off-topic, but POB as in 'the answer is "merely a matter of opinion" ' rather than POB as in 'answers will almost certainly be nothing more than opinion'.

Comment: Ok. FYI I shortened the sentence to what I thought was important. Should I just delete this question then?